# Reduce WinForm DotNet6.0 app size as it is too large

Tags: c#, winforms, .net-6.0

I have made a simple dotnet winform application that resides in the system tray.

I want my app to be downloaded and runnable for any user from about windows 8 to 11 (which it probably is already) as a single exe.
It only has a single icon, and tiny files (300kb total project size without bin and obj). No need for updates or anything.

I have made the program already a single exe file for win-64 computers. I think I have to use the options for SingleFile and self-contained to make it runnable on all windows user's computers.

However, my file size is 148mb. Is there any way to reduce this size to something small (I feel like it should be <50mb)? I only use two small nuget libraries.

Comment: How are you creating the exe? F6 in Visual Studio? What build profile are you using?

Comment: Your EXE probably contains all the .NET libraries that it references. That's what a self-contained app is, i.e. one that doesn't depend on a separate framework. If you want a smaller EXE then you need to make it rely on a separate, installed framework. .NET Framework 3.5 or maybe 4.0 seems the better option if you want the widest compatibility. Not many Windows 8 users are going to have .NET 6 installed. I very much doubt that it's even supported.

Comment: @jmcilhinney It's *supported* in Windows 7 (meaning *it works*, but of course the System itself, without an ESU, is not officially supported anymore)

Comment: @gunr2171 I'll have to have a look tonight but I am using the publish by right clicking on the project. It's a winexe, dotnet 6, targeted version 7.

Comment: @jmcilhinney with research it seems 4.8 is installed on Win10, but even though I tried to install 4.8, I can only seem to select dotnet 6, 5, 3.1 and 3 in the build options

Comment: If you are publishing the results using Core it contains the entire runtime Core library.  To check actual c# executable size go to project bin folder and check the exe file size which is just the c# executable without the reference libraries.

Comment: *"I can only seem to select dotnet 6, 5, 3.1 and 3 in the build options"*. That's because you created a .NET Core project in the first place. .NET 5 and later ae based on .NET Core. If you want to target the .NET Framework then you have to create a .NET Framework project in the first place. When you create a new project and select a template, those that target .NET Framework say so specifically in the name. When I want to target .NET Framework, I generally type "framework" into the filter box, so I don't pick the wrong one by mistake.

Comment: @jmcilhinney Ahh. that makes sense, thanks. I was getting confused what the differences were. If 3.1 is too outdated, I think I'll stick with 6 since the process to update to 6.0 for the user doesn't seem too bad and has instructions for the user :).

Comment: Have a look for ['app trimming'](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/app-trimming-in-net-5/), it cuts out classes and methods that are not explicitly called by your code